# What is the difference between validate() and validated() function in Laravel 5.8, PHP?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I could not find the different definition between the `validate()` and `validated()` function in the documentation on laravel.com website.

But in the `Validator` interface file, I have read the comment of the function as following:

```
/**
 * Run the validator's rules against its data.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function validate();

/**
 * Get the attributes and values that were validated.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function validated();
```

I do understand these comments, but when I write the code and test both functions, I did not see any difference. Both seem to act the same:

1. validates data.
2. if failed, redirects users to their previous page.
3. if succeeded, return validated data in an array.

So, what is the difference between these two function in Laravel 5.8?

In my case, I use the validation as following, because I do not want to redirect users back to their previous page when validation failed.

```
$validator = validator($array_data, $array_rules, $array_message);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // Do something
} else {
    $validated_data = $validator->validate();
    // Here I am not sure if I should use the validated() function, because I do not see the difference between these two functions.
    // $validated_data = $validator->validated();    
}
```

Comment: Side note: I really try hard to avoid directly calling the Validator. Consider using FormRequest classes instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's safe to use either, at least currently. [Here's the source for `validate()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.8.17/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L312):

```
public function validate()
{
    if ($this->fails()) {
        throw new ValidationException($this);
    }

    return $this->validated();
}
```

As you can see, the return value is the results of `validated()`.

That said, I'd personally use `validate()` to perform validation, and `validated()` to get the validated data. This should insulate you from potential future changes to the `validate()` function (if it were, say, changed to return a true/false instead) and result in slightly more readable code.

Comment: if you use both validate() and validated() function, it is like you call validated() function twice. Don't you think it is not necessary?

Comment: Like I said, that's my personal opinion. I feel like it leads to more readable code, and the performance impact is entirely negligible. You're free to disagree.

Comment: In my personal experience, I've found atleast one instance where simply calling `$validator->validated()` didn't do the job. I was submitting a form containing a multi file input as array and with validation rules in place to ensure a maximum number of files per submit.

While I was making a validator with `$validator = Validator::make(\request()->all(), ... )` and then calling `$validator->validated();`, it wouldn't work. I had to put a `$validator->validate();` before calling validated for it to finally work as intentded.

Comment: @SamikSengupta Correct, `Validator::make` doesn't run the validation. In OP's question, the `$validator->fails()` causes the validator to run. Different scenarios.